# Using Choreo analytics behind the proxy

Tags: wso2

I've installed WSO2 Api Manager 4.0.0 on internal server and I have no idea how to tell it to use proxy server to connect to Choreo analytics.
I see following error in the log:

```
:Provided authentication endpoint https://analytics-event-auth.choreo.dev/auth/v1 is not reachable.
```

I've tried to set `http_proxy, https_proxy, HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables with flag `java.net.useSystemProxies=true` to `api_manager.sh` but they seem to not work and I don't see any traffic coming from this server through proxy.
Adding java flags `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` didn't helped too.
If I start it from server with internet access then it works just fine with Choreo.

Is there any way to set the proxy for APIM?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager's gateway component talks to an API in the Analytics cloud in order to fetch required credentials to publish events to the cloud. The failure that you have pointed out occurs at the point of talking to this API. It appears that proxy settings have not been configured for this particular HTTP client. Please see [here](https://github.com/wso2/apim-analytics-publisher/blob/e742fd8fe75461c834fc0a2876d9a5653db0f047/component/publisher-client/src/main/java/org/wso2/am/analytics/publisher/auth/AuthClient.java#L39).

Event publishing is the next step and uses AMQP protocol. Therefore I think it would not go through the HTTP/S proxy. However, if the gateway has no access to the internet, this step will fail again regardless of the API call is fixed to honour the proxy settings.

Currently, analytics does not have the support to publish events through a proxy. It seems that in order to honour proxy settings in event publishing, the protocol needs to be changed to [Websocket](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-messaging-eventhubs/5.0.0-beta.6/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/EventHubClientBuilder.html#proxyOptions-com.azure.core.amqp.ProxyOptions-).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We will try to set the connection to Choreo on the firewall so we don't have to use proxy.